# action.php could not fetch the data from the database table

Tags: php

So i have to display out the row in a table that fetch from my database. I have a JQuery to fetch out code but it show me the error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\hopeplace\madmin\action.php on line 49

```
<?php 
//action.php
if(isset($_POST["action"]))
{

include('../connect.php');

if($_POST["action"] == 'fetch')
{
    $output='';
    $query ="SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE user_type ='user' ORDER BY user_name ASC";
    $statement = $Conndb-> prepare($query);
    $statement->execute()
    $result = $statement->fetchAll();//line 14
    $output .= '

        <table class="table table-hover">
            <tr>    
                <td>Full Name</td>
                <td>Email</td>
                <td>Status</td>
                <td>Action</td>
            </tr>

            ';
    foreach($result as $row){
        $status ='';
        if($row["user_status"] == 'Active'){

            $status = '<span class="label label-success">Active</span>';
        }
        else{

            $status = '<span class="label label-danger">Inactive</span>';
        }

        $output .= '
        <tr>
            <td>'.$row["user_name"].'</td>
            <td>'.$row["user_email"].'</td>
            <td>'.$status.'</td>
            <td><button type="button" name ="action" class="btn btn-info btn-xs action" data-user_id="'.$row["user_id"].'" data-user_status="'.$row["user_status"].'">Action</button></td>
        </tr>
        ';
    }

    $output .= '</table'>;//line 49
    echo $output;

}
}
?>
```

even I change the code to

```
$output .= '</table>';//line 49
```

it show me another error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   mysqli_stmt::fetchAll() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\hopeplace\madmin\action.php:14 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\hopeplace\madmin\action.php on line 14

Answer (score 1):

From the line:

```
$statement->execute()
```

It looks like you forgot to terminate it with a semicolon.

It should read:

```
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

`fetchAll()` is for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

`fetch_all()` is for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), which is seems like you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed up PDO and mysqli.
Try below code replacement which does the same with mysqli. 
    $output='';

```
$stmt = $this->db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();

//grab a result set
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();

//pull all results as an associative array
$result = $resultSet->fetch_all();
```